# Wrapping a visual studio database unit test in a transaction to eliminate database changes persisting

Tags: database, unit-testing, sql-server-2012, visual-studio-2015

I'm using VS 2015 Unit Tests for a SQL Server 2012 database.  I would like to be able to use the pre-test to insert the test data and wrap the whole unit test in a transaction which can be rolled back at the end of the test.  I've tried wrapping the entire test code in a TransactionScope (below) but it does not rollback the inserts.

```
            using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
        {
            SqlDatabaseTestActions testActions = this.dbo_Proc1TestData;
            // Execute the pre-test script
            // 
            System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLineIf((testActions.PretestAction != null), "Executing pre-test script...");
            SqlExecutionResult[] pretestResults = TestService.Execute(this.PrivilegedContext, this.PrivilegedContext, testActions.PretestAction);
            try
            {
                // Execute the test script
                // 
                System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLineIf((testActions.TestAction != null), "Executing test script...");
                SqlExecutionResult[] testResults = TestService.Execute(this.ExecutionContext, this.PrivilegedContext, testActions.TestAction);
            }
            finally
            {
                // Execute the post-test script
                // 
                System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLineIf((testActions.PosttestAction != null), "Executing post-test script...");
                SqlExecutionResult[] posttestResults = TestService.Execute(this.PrivilegedContext, this.PrivilegedContext, testActions.PosttestAction);
            }
        }
```

Are there any other ways to accomplish this without resorting to deleting the data in the post-test?

Comment: I found the answer in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833153.aspx

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the ExecutionContext and PrivilegedContext have already been created and therefore do not enlist in the transaction created by TransactionScope. The fix is to add calls to EnlistTransaction for each context inside the using statement:

```
        using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew))
        {
            this.ExecutionContext.Connection.EnlistTransaction(Transaction.Current);
            this.PrivilegedContext.Connection.EnlistTransaction(Transaction.Current);
```